# MySQL IF ELSE Look over

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have a stored procedure that use if elseif else in MySQL.  In the first one, no matter what params I pass in, I get null. Can anyone help me out?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CBattle`(IN btle varchar(50), OUT coun1 varchar(50), OUT coun2 varchar(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE shipnum int;
IF 2 != (SELECT COUNT(classes.country) FROM classes, outcomes, ships WHERE outcomes.ship = ships.name AND ships.class = classes.class AND outcomes.battle = btle )
THEN 
SET coun1 = null;
SET coun2 = null;
ELSE 
SET coun1 = (SELECT country FROM classes, outcomes, ships WHERE outcomes.ship = ships.name AND ships.class = classes.class AND outcomes.battle = btle LIMIT 1);
SET coun2 = (SELECT country FROM classes, outcomes, ships WHERE outcomes.ship = ships.name AND ships.class = classes.class AND outcomes.battle = btle LIMIT 1,1);
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Without looking at the actual data it's going to be impossible to help you.  All I can say is pull the queries out and run them directly to see if you can identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was some little MySQL mistake I was making.

Comment: Maybe..maybe not.  The `IF 2!=(select....` part is a bit weird.  I'm not sure why you'd want to send NULL back if it found exactly 2 different `country` relationships.  Nor am I sure as to whether ALL of the records you have tested have 2 `country` relationships.  But, those are data questions which can only be resolved if we knew what is in those tables... and you should be able to resolve by running the individual queries that make up the proc yourself.